# Beta Steam Uninstall

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, steam, beta

I jut installed Beta Steam for Ubuntu 12.04. And i can't open it, even with that command `steam steam://open/friends` it still won't start. So is there any possibility to uninstall it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can find it in Software Center, then great! Just click uninstall!

Otherwise, you way look for it in Synaptic, in search bar `steam`.

Finally, if none of these work, try typing `sudo apt-get remove steam`.

If none of these work, you can remove most of its files by pressing `CTRL-H` in your home folder and deleting the `.steam` directory.

Comment: You can delete the files after uninstalling, as Timo said.

Answer (score 2):

If you installed it through the deb that's floating around, you can just find it in the Software Center. After uninstalling, check your homefolder for the folders `Steam` and `.steam` which you can remove to get rid of it completely (including games).

Comment: The deal is that i don't have it on my SC (It's weird).

Comment: How did you install in the first place?

Comment: Uhm i downloaded .deb package via http://steamforlinux.com/?q=en/node/130 and autoopened with Software Center.

Comment: You need to click the "Show technical items" link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I just got rid of Steam for Linux, but prior to uninstalling I was unable to open Steam to uninstall the games. I was able to eliminate Steam from Ubuntu 12.04.2 by deleting both:

- `/home/username/.steam`
- `/home/username/.local/Steam`

The latter is which took up the most space because all the local game data is stored there.
Hope this helps anyone who was having troubles uninstalling Steam for Linux under Ubuntu 12.04.2

Answer (score -1):

For kill steam you need kill home/xxxx/.local/Steam

Para acabar completamente con Steam es necesario liquidar el directorio 
home/xxxx/.local/Steam.  No basta con eliminar home/xxxx/.Steam

Best Regards
Saludos